# Jackson: collection of [key:value, key:value2] to [key:[value1, value2]]

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I've an entity `Ent` which has a `collection<FacetValue>`.

```
public class Ent
{
    private List<FacetValue> facets;
}
```

Each `FacetValue` is like:

```
public class FacetValue
{
    private String facetName;
    private String facetValue;

    // getters & setters
}
```

I need to de/serialize these collection. In order to do that, I'm using a `JsonSerializer` to serialize each object:

```
public class FacetValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<FacetValue>
{

    @Override
    public void serialize(FacetValue value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {

        gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField(value.getKey(), value.getValue());
        gen.writeEndObject();

    }

}
```

And, a serialize for `Ent` objects:

```
public EntSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Ent> 
{
     @Override
     public void serialize(Ent ent, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
     {
         //...
         gen.writeFieldName("facets");
         gen.writeStartArray(value.getMetainfos().size());
         for (FacetValue facetValue : value.getFacets())
             gen.writeObject(facetValue);
         gen.writeEndArray();
     }
}
```

So, as you can figure out each `FacetValue` is basicly a `key:"object"` pair.

*The problem:*
    Each key can have several values. the way they are stored in a `Ent` object is like: `ent.getFacets.add(new FacetValue("k1", "v1"))` and `ent.getFacets.add(new FacetValue("k1", "v2"))`...

So, after serializing a `Ent` object I would generate a json like `{"facets":[{"k1":"v1"},{"k1":"v2"}]}`. I would like to get: `{"facets":[{"k1":["v1", "v2"]}]}`.

I'm not able to change `Ent` design. I'm only able to change Serializers and Deserializers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the serializer, I created a Map which holds the values that have the same key (using Java 8 streams)

```
public class EntSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Ent>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Ent ent, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        // ...
        gen.writeFieldName("facets");
        gen.writeStartArray(ent.getFacets().size());

        Map<String, List<FacetValue>> facetsByKey = 
                ent.getFacets().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FacetValue::getKey));
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<FacetValue>> entry : facetsByKey.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().size() == 1) {
                // generate {"k1":"v1"}
                gen.writeObject(entry.getValue().get(0));
            } else {
                // generate {"k1":["v1", "v2"]}
                gen.writeArrayFieldStart(entry.getKey());
                for (FacetValue facet : entry.getValue()) {
                    gen.writeString(facet.getValue());
                }
                gen.writeEndArray();
            }
        }

        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really obvious serializing them as you has proposed. However, each `FacetValue` is used by other entities. So, that's why I created two serializers, one for the entity and the other one for each `FacetValue`. So, I'm able to serialize whichever `FacetValue` object whereever it be.

Comment: you are adding new information not mentioned in the question. so far, it is only mentioned that in one entity, multiple facets can have same key and diff values. can you elaborate what is the output that you wish for a facet that is present in multiple entities?

Comment: also, I do not understand the purpose of FacetValue serializer, since it is doing the same as the default one

Comment: I'm using a `FacetValue` serializer in order to serialize a `FacetValue` of the same way. I only meant, it's a piece of code that Jackson detects to use when jackson is trying to serialize a `FacetValue`. For this reason, I'm using two serializers, one for `Ent` and the other one for `FacetValue`. Whichever entity has a collection of `FacetValue` Jackson is going to use the same serializer.

Comment: the first sentence "using a serializer..." is not clear AT ALL. the whole question and info is very confusing.... what is the problem exactly?? what is the desired output for facet that is present in multiple entities?? where is the answer lacking ?? examples please, no more confusing explanations